# Is my effort necessary and is my approach creating a suitable primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

I am trying to create a dimension table (`NewTable`) from an existing Data Warehouse table (`OldTable`) that doesn't have a primary key.

The `OldTable` holds distinct values in `[IdentifierCode]` and other values repeat around it. I also need to invoke 3 functions to add reporting context.

I want `IdentifierCode_ID` to be an INT column - as the `[IdentifierCode]` column is `VARCHAR(6)`.

My question is this: is using `ROW_NUMBER()` (as shown below) producing a suitably unique value?

My concern is that the row order on the live table could change if other rows are inserted to remediate missed codes.

**Edit**: `OldTable` has 500k rows in all and 227k when filtered with the `WHERE` clause

```sql
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LoadDate, StartDate, Product, IdentifierCode) AS IdentifierCode_ID,
    LoadDate, 
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    Product,
    IdentifierCode,
    OtherField1, OtherField2, OtherField3, OtherField4,
    Function1, Function2, Function3
INTO 
    NewTable
FROM 
    OldTable
WHERE
    GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS "The OldTable holds distinct values in [IdentifierCode]"--Then the table has a candidate for PK, whether declared or not. It's not clear what you mean by "doesn't have a primary key". PS What is "a constrained Primary Key column"? "achieve this "--Achieve what? "ROW_NUMBER() being inserted ..."? But that's not clear. "the order on the live table could change" What does that mean & how does it affect "ROW_NUMBER() being inserted ..." & how is that a problem? What's the situation & the problem? And what is the question? [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please: Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: *"My concern is that the row order on the live table could change if other rows are inserted to remediate missed codes."* <-yes if you run ROW_NUMBER() once on a table, and then insert/update/delete records and run it once again, you will get different row numbers for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unless you're either loading data once and never touching it again or are truncating NewTable before each load of a new date range, your approach will not work. ROW_NUMBER will restart at 1 and violate the primary key.

Even if you ARE truncating the table or only loading once ever, there is still a better way. Designate `IdentifierCode_ID` as an Identity column and SQL will take care of it for you. If the type is INT and IDENTITY is set, SQL will automatically add 1 to the last value when inserting a new row, you don't even have to assign it!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NewTable(
    [IdentifierCode_ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdentifierCode] VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
...
```

Also, make sure you consider what you'll do if you accidentally select an overlapping date range for subsequent loads and if values in the OldTable change - for example, add a restriction to the WHERE clause to exclude existing `IdentifierCode` values from the insert, and add a second query to update existing `IdentifierCode` values that have a different `LoadDate`, `StartDate`, etc.

```
...
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NewTable as N WHERE N.IdentifierCode = OldTable.IdentifierCode)
```

For updating existing rows that changed, you can do an INNER JOIN to select only existing rows and a WHERE clause for only rows that changed.

```
UPDATE NewTable
SET LoadDate = O.LoadDate, StartDate = O.StartDate, ... --don't forget to recalculate the functions!
FROM NewTable as N INNER JOIN OldTable as O on N.IdentifierCode = O.IdentifierCode
WHERE GETDATE() between O.StartDate and O.EndDate
  AND NOT (N.StartDate = O.StartDate and N.EndDate = O.EndDate ... )
```